# Webserver Unresponsive

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, php-fpm, website

I need some assistance on a new Apache2.4 and PHP-FPM server we have running. Intermittently the website becomes unresponsive We have only just moved over to PHP-FPM and didn't have this issue with the old server.

```
Checking the FPM log we're getting a lot of the following errors just before the site goes unresponsive
WARNING: pid 2897506, fpm_request_check_timed_out(), line 265: [pool www] child 3752421, script 'FILE PATH  Executing too slow   
WARNING: pid 2897506, fpm_request_check_timed_out(), line 265: [pool www] child 3750981, script 'FILE PATH  Executing too slow   
WARNING: pid 2897506, fpm_request_check_timed_out(), line 265: [pool www] child 3749995, script 'FILE PATH  Executing too slow   
WARNING: pid 2897506, fpm_request_check_timed_out(), line 265: [pool www] child 3749599, script 'FILE PATH  Executing too slow   
WARNING: pid 2897506, fpm_request_check_timed_out(), line 265: [pool www] child 3748928, script 'FILE PATH  Executing too slow   
WARNING: pid 2897506, fpm_request_check_timed_out(), line 265: [pool www] child 3747019, script 'FILE PATH  Executing too slow   
WARNING: pid 2897506, fpm_request_check_timed_out(), line 265: [pool www] child 3744773, script 'FILE PATH  Executing too slow   
WARNING: pid 2897506, fpm_request_check_timed_out(), line 265: [pool www] child 3731142, script 'FILE PATH  Executing too slow   
WARNING: pid 2897506, fpm_request_check_timed_out(), line 265: [pool www] child 3731131, script 'FILE PATH  Executing too slow   
WARNING: pid 2897506, fpm_request_check_timed_out(), line 265: [pool www] child 3731015, script 'FILE PATH  Executing too slow   
WARNING: pid 2897506, fpm_request_check_timed_out(), line 265: [pool www] child 3730870, script 'FILE PATH  Executing too slow   
WARNING: pid 2897506, fpm_request_check_timed_out(), line 265: [pool www] child 3730867, script 'FILE PATH  Executing too slow
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to look? FPM is a new concept to me and I want to make sure I've configured it correctly.

most recent slowlog errors during our outage

[pool www] pid 596016
script_filename = *Path to script*

[0x00007f3389814410] __construct() *Path to script*

[0x00007f33898142f0] getInstance() *Path to script*

[0x00007f3389814220] loadUser() *Path to script*

[0x00007f3389814140] checkValidUser() *Path to script*

[pool www] pid 617256

script_filename = *Path to script*

[0x00007f33898142f0] session_start() *Path to script*

[0x00007f33898141d0] INCLUDE_OR_EVAL *Path to script*

[pool www] pid 617257

script_filename = *Path to script*

[0x00007f33898132f0] session_start() *Path to script*

[0x00007f33898131d0] INCLUDE_OR_EVAL *Path to script*

[pool www] pid 617258

script_filename = *Path to script*

[0x00007f33898132f0] session_start() *Path to script*

[0x00007f33898131d0] INCLUDE_OR_EVAL *Path to script*

[pool www] pid 617285

script_filename = *Path to script*

[0x00007f33898142f0] session_start() *Path to script*

[0x00007f33898141d0] INCLUDE_OR_EVAL *Path to script*

Comment: More likely that you DID have the issue before but it was not logged, because mod_php does not log slow scripts. Configure the php-fpm slow log to get more information.

Comment: The website wasn't going completely unresponsive on the old server. Is there anything within PHP-FPM which might be causing this to happen where it didn't with mod_PHP?

Comment: What did you find in the slow log?

Comment: I've added the most recent errors at the time of the most recent crash to my post. You'll have to excuse me I'm new to PHP-FPM and trying to work my head around it.